# Vectorizing double summations using R

Tags: r, math, addition

I am struggling with translating this function into R using via vectorization technique:

[image]

Where all I have been able to do so far is this:

```
c <- matrix(1:9, 3)
z <- 1:3

sum(abs(outer(z, z,"-")) * c)/sum(c)
```

But I don't think its necessarily correct. I tried a for-loop version but that is too long and my answer is likely wrong anyway. Anyone keen on this? What am I missing (or doing wrong)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the for-loop version is wrong? You should write a simple for-loop version and test it with small examples, then write clever vectorised function versions and check they agree. Is the answer 0.88888 in this case?

Comment: For my answer I got .888. Using what I had.

the for loop version gave me some negative number and I realized I had some inconsistencies in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a double-loop version:

```
q = 
function(z,c){
num = 0
 for(i in 1:length(z)){
  for(j in 1:length(z)){
    num = num + abs(z[i]-z[j]) * c[i,j]
  }
 }
num/sum(c)
}
```

Here's your vectorised version, functionised:

```
q2 = 
function(z,c){sum(c*abs(outer(z,z,'-')) /sum(c))}
```

Not a great difference in timing between them really for a small matrix:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(q(z,c), q2(z,c))
Unit: microseconds
     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
  q(z, c) 15.368 15.7505 16.59644 16.0225 16.6290 30.346   100   b
 q2(z, c) 12.232 12.8885 13.79178 13.2225 13.6585 44.085   100  a
```

But for a larger test it's a big win:

```
> c2 = matrix(runif(100*100),100,100)
> z2 = runif(100)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(q(z2,c2), q2(z2,c2))
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq       max neval cld
  q(z2, c2) 7437.031 7588.131 8046.92272 7794.927 8332.104 10729.799   100   b
 q2(z2, c2)   74.742   78.647   94.20153   86.113  100.125   188.428   100  a 
>
```

Numeric difference is within floating point tolerance:

```
> q(z2,c2) - q2(z2,c2)
[1] 6.661338e-16
```

So unless anyone has faster code, I'd stick with what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

As perfectly explained by @Spacedman, your approach is very efficient, but if you still want to go faster you could try Rcpp :

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(code='
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double qRcpp(const Rcpp::NumericVector z, const Rcpp::NumericMatrix cm){
  int zlen = z.length();
  if(!(zlen == cm.nrow() && cm.nrow() == cm.ncol()))
    Rcpp::stop("Invalid sizes");

  double num = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < zlen ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < zlen ; j++){
      num = num + std::abs(z[i]-z[j]) * cm(i,j);
    }
  } 
  return num / Rcpp::sum(cm);
}

')
```

Benchmark :

```
c2 = matrix(runif(100*100),100,100)
z2 = runif(100)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(q(z2,c2), q2(z2,c2),qRcpp(z2,c2))
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr       min         lq        mean    median         uq       max neval
#      q(z2, c2) 10273.035 10976.3050 11680.85554 11348.763 11765.2010 44115.632   100
#     q2(z2, c2)    64.292    67.9455    80.56427    75.543    86.3565   244.019   100
#  qRcpp(z2, c2)    21.042    21.9180    25.30515    24.256    26.8860    56.403   100
```